# How to adjust the height and bold the text of the tab's in android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, tabs

Can someone tell me how should i adjust the height of my three tabs's diagrammatically rather than in xml because my picture overlaps the wording therefore i had to adjust my tab's slightly longer but width still remain the same... And how should i bold the text string in the indicator at the same time? But how should i do that in my current context of code i'm rather in android..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom layout for your tabs here is an example source on how to do this
 [android-custom-tabs](http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/)